# PHP - Remove duplicates with foreach?

Tags: php, foreach, duplicates

I have a array of page numbers:

```
foreach($elements as $el) {
$pageno = $el->getAttribute("pageno");

echo  $pageno ;
}
```

Sadly it contains duplicates. I tried the follow code but it won't return a thing:

```
foreach(array_unique($elements) as $el) {
$pageno = $el->getAttribute("pageno");

echo  $pageno ;
}
```

How to remove the duplicate page numbers? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It works as I'd expect, https://3v4l.org/iPoZk. Perhaps `$elements` is not an array? `getAttribute` sounds like domdocument object maybe?

Comment: Why not use [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton he actually use array_unique in the second foreach

Comment: @MacBooc That makes even less sense to me unless it's a multi-dimensional array. In which case, just use it twice.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton i think it's even an array of object with different values while he use `getAttribute` inside his loop, so array_unique can't work here imo

Comment: @MacBooc But you are assuming the structure of the array. OP hasn't provided enough details about what they are trying to do imo.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton i agree

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since I do not have your data structure, I am providing a generic solution. This can be optimized if we know the structure of `$elements` but the below should work for you.

```
$pageNos = array();
foreach($elements as $el) {
   $pageno = $el->getAttribute("pageno");
   if(!in_array($pageno, $pageNos))
   {
       echo $pageno ;
       array_push($pageNos,$pageno);
   }
}
```

Basically we are just using an additional array to store the printed values. Each time we see a new value, we print it and add it to the array.

Comment: Thank you! This worked very well. Got a syntax error though. Fixed by adding a ; after 'array_push($pageNos,$pageno)'.  :) Is there also a way to sort this array? It echo's: 7 6 8 1 2 3 4 5 now. I would love to have it like: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8.

Comment: @Jack You could probably just do PHP's `sort()` after the foreach and then loop through the elements afterwards again to display the page numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the answers already provided, you can also use [array_unique()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

A very simple example:

```
$pageno = array_unique($pageno);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a temporary list of page numbers. Duplicate instances will then be removed from the list of $elements:

```
// Create a temporary list of page numbers
$temp_pageno = array();
foreach($elements as $key => $el) {
    $pageno = $el->getAttribute("pageno");
    if (in_array($pageno, $temp_pageno)) {
        // Remove duplicate instance from the list
        unset($elements[$key]);
    }
    else {
        // Ad  to temporary list
        $temp_pageno[] = $pageno;
    }

    echo  $pageno ;
}
```